# Django: Can't change default language

Tags: python, django, internationalization, translation

I have been developing for some time in `en-gb` language code. Now arriving closer to the release date I was going to switch the default language to `en-us`, but whatever I do the initial `request.LANGUAGE_CODE` is set to `en-gb` even for unregistered users.

FYI, I would actually like to keep the time_zone to London and simply change the default language to American English. For now I have changed both just to get it working, but still no joy.

```
#TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/London'
TIME_ZONE = 'US/Eastern'

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
#LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-gb'

ugettext = lambda s: s

LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', ugettext('American English')),
    ('en-gb', ugettext('British English'))
)

USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
```

What could I be missing? Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`LANGUAGE_CODE` is only the default when Django can't find what language to use. You probably already have `en-gb` in your session or a cookie which Django picks up on.

Have a read through [How Django discovers language preference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference) for more information on the steps Django takes to determine a request's language.

Comment: Thanks Simeon, it is strange, even in browser "Private mode", which should not have any cookies I still get en-gb. despite having changed my browser locale to USA as well.  The link you sent is for Django 1.3.  And the page is removed for 1.4. Strange.. still investigating

Comment: For Django 1.4 it can be found here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4//topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference

Comment: Thanks. Despite all my efforts, trying to emulate the American environment here in London (proxy, browser locale language switcher, incognito mode) I didn't succeed and called a friend in US to test the site. And he gets the American English by default. So its all good. :D

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [how Django discovers language preference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference).

In your case, I bet you have `LocaleMiddleware` enabled, and it's getting your language from the `Accept-Language` header that your browser sends with every request. You can change that header in your browser's preferences, although many users are unaware of this and stay at whatever the default was on their system. In Firefox, for instance, you can change this at Preferences, Content, Choose (under Languages).

Answer (score 1):

Had an issue for a while with this... I later discovered a middleware was missing in my settings.py file... thats -> `'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',`

[How Django discovers language preference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference)

[image: Where to place the middleware]

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/django/django/pull/17151

you find the solution here
you need to customize the Local MiddleWare to skip the preferred browser language