# Set or change the DEFAULT_LANGUAGE in Django

Tags: python, django, internationalization

**I want the default language of my site to be Persian, not English!
and DEFAULT_LANGUAGE is not working for me !**

A part of my settings.py file :

```
LANGUAGES = (
    ('fa','Persian'),
    ('en','English'),
)

DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = 1

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'fa'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Tehran'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

I also read these and they did not help:

[Set or change the default language dynamically according to the user - Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42953521/set-or-change-the-default-language-dynamically-according-to-the-user-django)

[Django how to set the default language in the i18n_patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42553488/django-how-to-set-the-default-language-in-the-i18n-patterns)

[Django: Can't change default language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14562564/django-cant-change-default-language)

[Django: default language i18n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816033/django-default-language-i18n)

Please help me. thanks!

Comment: clear the cookies in your browser, normally once picked a language, they set a language cookie.

Comment: `DEFAULT_LANGUAGE` is not a Django setting. It is not in the docs. Or am I missing something? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/

Comment: `DEFAULT_LANGUAGE` is also not in the Django source code: https://github.com/django/django/search?q=DEFAULT_LANGUAGE

Answer (score 3):

In settings.py you probably have this middleware,and it takes default language as your browser's language.

```
'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware'
```

Comment: So your suggestion is that they remove it if they want to manually control the locale?

Comment: Yes remove and add custom middleware

Answer (score 1):

just change this:
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'fa-ir'

[python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python)
[django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django)

[List Of Language Code](https:///www.fincher.org/Utilities/CountryLanguageList.shtml)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Here is fastest and simplest solution. In my case Django=="3.1"
https://github.com/yifaneye/django-default-language

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).